# Getting auto increment id with insert_id

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the auto increment id from my 'users' table when a new user registers and be able to use that id for another query I have right after the user is inserted into the 'users' table.

I want to use the 'users' table's 'id' for the 'user_id' in my 'payment_status' table. I am trying different ways to use the `insert_id` function, but I cannot get the id to dump in my first query. Even then, when I am able to get it to dump, I am not sure how to get it from that and use it for what I am trying to do. Could anyone provide some guidance of how to do this?

```
if($validation->passed()) {
            $user = new User();

            $salt = Hash::salt(32);

            try {
                $user->create(array(
                    'firstname' => Input::get('firstname'),
                    'lastname' => Input::get('lastname'),
                    'email' => Input::get('email'),
                    'phone_number' => Input::get('phone_number'),
                    'username' => Input::get('username'),
                    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
                    'salt' => $salt,
                    'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'group' => 1,
                    //var_dump($id->insert_id)
                    var_dump(mysqli::$insert_id)
                ));
                $success = "You have successfully created an account. We will notify you once the account has been approved. Then you will be able to login.";
                echo $success;


//Query to add user's name to payment_status db table

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $id = ( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ? $_SESSION['id'] : "" );
                $user_id = ( isset( $_SESSION['id'] ) ? $_SESSION['id'] : "" );
                $firstname = Input::get('firstname');
                $payment_name = "Owes";
                $payment_id = 1;
                $payment_amount = 0;



            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
            /* check connection */
               if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
                    exit();
                }
            $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO payment_status (id, user_id, firstname, payment_name, payment_id, payment_amount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

                if ( false===$stmt ) {
              // Check Errors for prepare
              die(' Owes DB prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
            }
            $stmt->bind_param('iissii', $id, $user_id, $firstname, $payment_name, $payment_id, $payment_amount);
                if ( false===$stmt ) {
                  // Check errors for binding parameters
                  die('Owes DB bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
                }
            $stmt->execute();

                if ( false===$stmt ) {
                  die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
                }
                // Debug
                var_dump($con->insert_id);

                // Output:
                // int(1)
            }
```

UPDATE: USER CLASS ADDED

```
<?php
class User {
    private $_db,
            $_data,
            $_sessionName,
            $_cookieName,
            $_isLoggedIn;

    public function __construct($user = null) {
        $this->_db = DB::getInstance();

        $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
        $this->_cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');

        if(!$user) {
            if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)) {
                $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

                if($this->find($user)) {
                    $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
                } else {
                    // process Logout
                }
            }
        } else {
            $this->find($user);
        }
    }

    public function update($fields = array(), $id = null) {

        if(!$id && $this->isLoggedIn()) {
            $id = $this->data()->id;
        }
        //echo $this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields);

        //if(!$this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields)) {
            //throw new Exception('There was a problem updating!');
        //}
        try {
            if(!$this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields)) {
                throw new Exception('There was a problem updating!');
            }
        }
           catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "An error occurred";
        throw $e;
    }
    finally {
                //This overrides the exception as if it were never thrown
        return "\nException erased";
    }
    try {
    echo asdf();
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "\nResult: " . $e->getMessage();
}
         //if(!$this->_db->update('users', $id, $fields)) { 
        // throw new Exception('There was a problem updating!')->getMessage(); 
         //}
    }

    public function create($fields = array()) {


        if(!$this->_db->insert('users', $fields)) {
            throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account:' .  $this->_db->errorMessage());

        }
    }

    public function find($user = null) {
        if($user) {
            $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
            $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

            if($data->count()) {
                $this->_data = $data->first();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function login($username = null, $password = null, $remember = false) {

        if(!$username && !$password && $this->exists()) {
            Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);
        } else {
            $user = $this->find($username);

            if($user) {
                if($this->data()->password === Hash::make($password, $this->data()->salt)) {
                    Session::put($this->_sessionName, $this->data()->id);

                    if($remember) {
                        $hash = Hash::unique();
                        $hashCheck = $this->_db->get('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

                        if(!$hashCheck->count()) {
                            $this->_db->insert('users_session', array(
                                'user_id' => $this->data()->id,
                                'hash' => $hash
                            ));
                        } else {
                            $hash = $hashCheck->first()->hash;
                        }

                        Cookie::put($this->_cookieName, $hash, Config::get('remember/cookie_expiry'));
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }
        return false;
    }

    public function hasPermission($key) {
        $group = $this->_db->get('groups', array('id', '=', $this->data()->group));

        if($group->count()) {
            $permissions = json_decode($group->first()->permissions, true);

            if($permissions[$key] == true) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function exists() {
        return (!empty($this->_data)) ? true : false;
    }

    public function logout() {

        $this->_db->delete('users_session', array('user_id', '=', $this->data()->id));

        Session::delete($this->_sessionName);
        Cookie::delete($this->_cookieName);
    }

    public function data() {
        return $this->_data;
    }
    public function isLoggedIn() {
        return $this->_isLoggedIn;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You could return the last inserted id at the end of your $user->create() method.  Then you get that value in your try, e.g. $lastId = $user->create(array(...))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use mysqli::$insert_id after your create query

```
$user->create(array(
'firstname' => Input::get('firstname'),
'lastname' => Input::get('lastname'),
'email' => Input::get('email'),
'phone_number' => Input::get('phone_number'),
'username' => Input::get('username'),
'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
'salt' => $salt,
'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'group' => 1,                
));
var_dump(mysqli::$insert_id);
```

Or maybe it will be

```
var_dump($user->insert_id);
```

Comment: I get this error for the mysqli:: one `Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: mysqli::$insert_id in`...then the one with the variable `$user`, I get this error...Notice: Undefined property: User::$insert_id in...But it successfully registers the user, so it doesn't break the code, but it comes back NULL.

Comment: The first one is because you don't use the mysql class to create an user and for the second, what's the framework you're using ?

Comment: It's one from youtube. From phpacademy. If it would help, I could post some of my user class in my question.

Comment: I added my user class.

Comment: Can you try a $user->id or if it doesn't work a var_dump($user) just after insertion please  ( instead of var_dump($user->insert_id)?

Comment: This was the $user dump... `object(User)#6 (5) { ["_db":"User":private]=> object(DB)#3 (6) { ["_pdo":"DB":private]=> object(PDO)#4 (0) { } ["_query":"DB":private]=> object(PDOStatement)#7 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(154) "INSERT INTO users (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `phone_number`, `username`, `password`, `salt`, `joined`, `group`) Values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" } ["_error":"DB":private]=> bool(false) ["_results":"DB":private]=> array(0) { } ["_count":"DB":private]=> int(1) ["_errmsg":"DB":private]=> string(0) "" }`

Comment: `["_data":"User":private]=> NULL ["_sessionName":"User":private]=> string(4) "user" ["_cookieName":"User":private]=> string(4) "hash" ["_isLoggedIn":"User":private]=> NULL } `